# Как повесить один обработчик событий на несколько инпутов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 4 **инпута**. На них нужно повесить одинаковый обработчик событий. Написал код ,но что-то делаю не правильно при **фокусе** на **инпуте** выдаёт ошибку. *"Uncaught TypeError: inp[i] is undefined"* По логике перебираю все элементы и на каждый вешаю обработчик события, но не работает. Как правильно повесить один обработчик на несколько инпутов?

```html
                        <input minlength="8" type="text" class="catalogNumber" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона">
```

```js
let inp = document.querySelectorAll('.catalogNumber');



for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
  inp[i].addEventListener('focus', _ => {
    if(!/^\+\d*$/.test(inp[i].value))
      inp[i].value = '+';
  });
  inp[i].addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if(!/\d/.test(e.key))
      e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="catalogNumber" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона">
<input class="catalogNumber" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона">
<input class="catalogNumber" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона">
<input class="catalogNumber" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуй.

```
let inp = document.querySelectorAll('.catalogNumber');

inp.forEach((item)=>{
   item.addEventListener('focus', _ => {
    if(!/^\+\d*$/.test(item.value))
      item.value = '+';
  });
  item.addEventListener('keypress', e =>      {
    if(!/\d/.test(e.key))
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```